# How to find image similarity on textual image in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am learning opencv and working on some test cases for research but the problem is that i am getting image similarity included the black region of the image. My purpose is to check the image similarity and place the each letter in the same folder (for example all images with 'A' letter should be in one folder and all the images with 'B' letter should be in the same folder) for that purpose I am finding image similarity. the problem is the black region in my images.

these are the images i am having

[image]
[image]

now I want to find the similarity between these images and place them accordingly

**the problem in my code is all the images have similarity morethan .90 which should be not possible for all images**

this is my code

```
def get_similarity(img_1, img_2):
    pix1 = img_1.convert('L').load()
    pix2 = img_2.convert('L').load()
    match_count = 0
    pix1_white_count = 0
    pix2_white_count = 0

    for y in range(0, img_1.height):
        for x in range(0, img_1.width):
            if pix1[x, y] == pix2[x, y] and pix2[x, y] == 255:
                match_count += 1
            if pix2[x, y] == 255:
                pix2_white_count += 1
            if pix1[x, y] == 255:
                pix1_white_count += 1

    # no of pixels have more than 10% variation
    if float(pix1_white_count - pix2_white_count) / float(pix1_white_count + pix2_white_count) >= 1.5:
        return 0
    return float(match_count)/float(pix2_white_count)
```

**Need to find similarity only on white region of the image or you can say between text**

the algo here i am working on it counts the white pixels on both images and then find the variation accordingly

**but it is giving index out of range on this line**

```
  if pix1[x, y] == pix2[x, y] and pix2[x, y] == 255:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want similarity of the white region, use [moments](https://www.learnopencv.com/find-center-of-blob-centroid-using-opencv-cpp-python/). This uses the pixel intensity, so for your image will ignore the black pixels (intensity = 0.) and use the white pixels (intensity = 1.)

Looks like [this tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/shape-matching-using-hu-moments-c-python/) might help explain how they can be used. In fact, using Hu moments as implemented in OpenCV's matchShapes() function will give a good idea of the image similarity, so you can use that function instead of your example.

Answer (score 0):

The convention in Numpy is that the `y` coordinate is first, then `x`. So you need:

```
pix1[y,x]
```

Comment: the error here is index out of range the error is same now